# Weird DOM issue when using browser back button on a slow connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am a JavaScript developer that works on a A/B testing team for a hotel company. I write the code that will take one of our web pages and create alternate versions so we can test to see what version works better.

I have been having a problem with one of my tests that is driving me insane.  We are doing a test that redesigns how the rates shown on our page that shows available rooms.

Everything works when you go forwards through the website, clicking on links and buttons. But when you use the browser’s back button to go back to the rooms & rates page, something weird happens. It’s like the DOM changes.  My jQuery each() loops don’t capture all of the nodes anymore.  Some of the nodes are skipped and sometimes it mixes elements from different nodes.

What's even more maddening is this usually intermittent -- it doesn't happen consistantly!

I have determined this happens only when someone has a slow internet connection.  I couldn’t reproduce the problems our QA team was finding until I used the Throttling feature in Chrome developer tools to slow down my connection to regular 3G speeds.

Can anyone shed light on behavioral differences of the back button vs initial page load? Are there any differences with respect to cache, JS events, etc.?

Comment: Perhaps an issue with checking cookies / permissions and since the connection is intermittent the call doesn't go through or returns faulty data?

Comment: Does your A/B testing have anything to do with manipulating how caching works? Perhaps scripts that were not supposed to be cached are being run on alternate versions of the web page when navigating using the back button.

Comment: We'll need to know a lot more about how that page works to do more than guess. For example, how is the page content generated? I assume you use ajax to return results from your api? If so, how exactly are you displaying the content? Are you using something like react, vue.js, ...some other framework?  You'll really need to show us the code that does all that, and your scraping code that is failing. Also, if you make a minimum example with just the bare minimum content, does the behaviour persist? It's not really possible to answer your question in its current form.

Comment: ^ That said, if I had to guess (and we do), I'd say that on a slow connection, the page refresh is reloading the previous DOM structure, then your `jQuery each()` starts running, and either during that loop or after, your ajax call returns results and clobbers the DOM changes youve made.......sounds weak to me but Id start by ruling that out, maybe by making sure that my test code runs *after* all results are fully loaded

Comment: DelightedD0D -- I had thought the same thing about Ajax calls clobbering the DOM. But if I hold my code back until the Ajax calls are complete the same thing still happens.  I wish I could post my code, but it is proprietary, quite complex, and is about 250 lines long when you take out the comments.
Surreal -- Thanks for the suggestion about cookies and permissions, but my code doesn't check on any of that.
Patrick -- I don't manipulate the caching, but maybe the source code does. I will check with the other developers on that front.

Comment: You have to put an @ in front of his handle for him to know you sent that.